# why Cut,Copy,Paste is not working in Mozilla Firefox and Google Chrome browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, copy, paste, execcommand

I tried to create a RichText Editor using jQuery with the help of execCommand().

But the following code:

```
document.execCommand('cut', false, null); 

document.execCommand('copy', false, null);

document.execCommand('paste', false, null);
```

Is not working in Mozilla Firefox, Google Chrome and some other browsers.

Are there any possibilities to do the Cut, Copy and Paste actions using execCommand() or there is any other method to do the Cut, Copy and Paste actions in my RichText Editor?

Answer (score 3):

It's easy to solve this problem, follow these steps:
Go to "about:config" no quotes on Firefox  and then hit the "i'll be careful, I promise" button, next type "dom.event.clipboardevents.enabled" then double click it, so the value is false. And that should do the trick.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From Chrome 42 and Firefox 41, **document.execCommand('cut')** and **document.execCommand('copy')** will work, but only on semi trusted events. See here https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-clipboard-apis-20140313/#semi-trusted-events

Like this for example:

```js
document.getElementById('copy').onmousedown = function() {
  console.log(document.execCommand('copy'))
}

document.getElementById('cut').onmousedown = function() {
  console.log(document.execCommand('cut'))
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
<button id="copy">Copy</button>
<button id="cut">Cut</button>
```

On Chrome **document.execCommand('paste')** will work the same way but requires an extension to be installed to allow it. Without extension, it won't work. To allow it, you need to include this **"clipboarRead"** in the permissions in your **manifest.json** file. Like this:

```
permissions: {
    ...
    "clipboardRead"
    ...
}
```